# Mensagem ao final de na.omit

Tags: r, matriz

Estou usando o comando `na.omit(matrix.work)` e ao final aparece a mensagem:

```
attr(,"na.action")
[1]  3 11
attr(,"class"
```

Alguém sabe como posso suprimir esta mensagem, pois não quero que ela apareça por estar carregando o conteúdo em uma variável.

Answer (score 2):

Essa mensagem não é um problema... São apenas atributos que a função coloca na matriz resultante. Uma matriz com esses atributos continuará se comportanto como uma matriz. Basta ignorá-los.

Dito isso, se você ainda quiser excluí-lo, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
a <- matrix(rep(c(NA, 1:4), each = 20), ncol = 10, byrow = T)
b <- na.omit(a)
attr(b, "na.action") <- NULL
b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[5,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[6,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
[7,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
[8,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4
```

Na linha que tem `attr(b, "na.action") <- NULL` você está atribuindo `NULL` ao atributo que a função `na.omit` acrescentou, o que é equivalente a excluí-lo.

Uma forma mais concisa, mas menos intuitiva é fazer:

```
b <- na.omit(a)[T,T]
```

Isso resulta em uma matriz sem atributos extras por uma característica da função `[`, que pode ser encontrada na docuemntação (`?"["`):

> Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except
>   names, dim and dimnames.